# cannot launch virtualbox after reloading

Tags: virtualbox

Having issues with Virtualbox on 16.04LTS
Couldn't get former session to start (which has all my Windows 10 apps).
Completely removed Virtualbox from command line.
Reloaded from software center 5.0.4.
It appears in the software center list of installed apps.
When launched, get the following error.

Failed to create the VirtualBoxClient COM object.

The application will now terminate.

Document is empty.

Location: '/home/al/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml', line 1 (0), column 1.

/build/virtualbox-n1JPUg/virtualbox-5.0.40-dfsg/src/VBox/Main/src-server/VirtualBoxImpl.cpp[534] (nsresult VirtualBox::init()).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: VirtualBoxWrap
Interface: IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}

On inspection, there is no Virtual VMs directory.
I physically added it back in, but the error is still the same on launch, either command line of graphical.
I was smart enough to back up my old Virtual VMs directory structure, but can't get this new install to fly.

Update - I went back and tried command line (Sudo Virtualbox), and it loads to the session menu. All my old session selections are there., but of course inaccessible. There's a ghost in the machine!

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So the error came back after more than a year? Did [the solution there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841047/virtualbox-cannot-create-com-object/841136) not help this time? You should better not run virtualbox as root, as it will lead to all kinds of permission issues.

Comment: That's the only way it ran previously. Now, however, it doesn't run at all, even with a purge and reinstall!